# Java input random numbers and keep a counter for each number

Tags: java

So I am trying to create a loop that accepts number "0 - 10". If it is less than "0" than the loop exits and the program prints out all the numbers and the number of times each was entered. So Lets say you enter values like `1 2 3 4 5 1` It will print out something like `Number:1  Times Entered:2` then next line will print out `Number:2 Times Entered:1`. If it goes higher than 10 I will just give them an input error. If someone can just help me out creating the correct variables and format I think I can take it from there. Here is what I have thus far... I know it's not correct but this is the idea I am trying to do.

```
import java.io.*;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

      InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
      BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(reader);
      String str;
      Integer[] numbers = new Integer[1000]
      int count = 0;

      str = input.readLine();
      while(str != null){
         numbers[count] = Integer.parseInt(str);

         // Here I will create some [if else] statements like
         if(numbers < 0)
            break;
         else if(numbers >= 0 || numbers <= 50)
            numbers[count]++;
         else
            System.out.print("You must enter a value less than 51");
      } // Close while loop here

      System.out.println("Number:" + number + " Times Entered:" + count);
   } 

}
```

Comment: Create an array of `int` from of length `10`.  Each element in the array represents a valid input (1-10 - but you'll need to zero index the access).  Use the value the use enters as an index into this array and update it's value by incrementing it...

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;

public class Demo {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

  InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
  BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(reader);
  String str;
  int i,number;
  Integer[] numbers = new Integer[10];
  int count = 0;
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    numbers[i]=0;
  str = input.readLine();
  while(str != null){
     number = Integer.parseInt(str);

     // Here I will create some [if else] statements like
     if(number == 0)
        break;
     else if(number >= 0 && number <= 10)
        numbers[number-1]++;
     else
        System.out.print("You must enter a value less than 11");
str = input.readLine();
  } // Close while loop here
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
     System.out.println("Number:" + (i+1) + " Times Entered:" + numbers[i]);
   } 

}
```

This should work.And put some efforts form your side so that you can learn